# Cannot Use Azure Service Token Provider

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which attempts to use `AzureServiceTokenProvider`, but an exception is thrown when calling `GetAccessTokenAsync`.

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var result = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
```

This exception is thrown when Managed Identities is turned off.

```
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This exception is thrown when Managed Identities is turned on.

```
[Error] Executed 'MyFunction' (Failed, Id=89446c8d-6d74-44e3-ae97-73ac31cbdb6b)
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

Comment: Is the error thrown by GetAccessTokenAsync?

Comment: @juunas, yes it's thrown by GetAccessTokenAsync.

Comment: Did you turn on system assigned managed identity or user assigned?

Comment: The second exception is when System Managed Identity is turned on.  The first exception is when System Managed Identity is turned off.

Comment: Okay that's really odd then :(

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming after enabling Managed identity because your DB is not allowing function app. 
You Can Fix this by 
1. Go to Azure Database in Azure Portal
2. Click on **IAM**
3. Adding Role
4. Search for your function app 
5. save everything 
6. Re-Run the Function app